# After setting a new drive to be the home partition, where can I find the old /home files?

Tags: partition, fstab

I recently bought a new hard drive and set it to be my `/home` partition. The old one used to be on the root partition, so I just added `/dev/sdXX` to my `fstab` file. The drive where the root partition lives is quite small, so I was wondering where the old `/home` files are now. I just want to remove them to free some disk space (I had already backed up any important stuff into my new `~`). Is there a way to access these files without commenting my `/home` line in the fstab file and rebooting to manually delete the files in the old home directory?

Answer (score 0):

The old files are still there in their directory, and will appear when the new filesystem is unmounted. All you have to do to see them is log out of all sessions, switch to a tty (Ctrl+Alt+F3 to switch to tty3), and log in as root. As the home directory for root is `/root`, it is not affected by the new `/home` filesystem. Once you're in as root, you may unmount the `/home` filesystem with `umount /home`. You may now do what you wish with your old files. If you'd like, you can transfer them into your new home directory by mounting the new filesystem on `/mnt` with `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` where `/dev/sdb1` is your new home partition. Once you've finished everything, unmount the new home filesystem if you mounted it with `umount /mnt`, then re-mount it in the home directory simply with `mount /home`.

Answer (score -1):

logout as user, then run as root `umount /home && mv /home /home.old && mkdir /home && mount /home`